# Yii - Cactiveform, cform, form builder - confusion

Tags: yii, yii-cformmodel, yii-cform

Those are three concepts on Yii that I really don't get what should we use, on what scenarios?

Can anyone be kind enough to clarify those Yii elements, and on what situation should we use them?

Answer (score 1):

In documentation of [CForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm) one can read the following:

> ...we can divide a form
>   in two parts: those that specify each individual form inputs, and
>   those that decorate the form inputs. A CForm object represents the former part...

...and `CActiveForm` represents the latter.

In other words, `CForm` specifies elements of the form but `CActiveForm` (being a widget) renders it.

Looking at the source code we state that `CForm` can also [render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm#render-detail) itself and its rendering relies on and is wrapped by `CActiveForm` widget by introducing its configuration property [activeForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm#activeForm-detail), though rendering input elements and buttons is implemented by its own methods [renderElements()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm#renderElements-detail) and [renderButtons()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm#renderButtons-detail) relatively. By default their implementations rely on classes using [CHtml](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml)'s static methods what is exactly the same (or almost exactly the same) what `CActiveForm`'s rendering methods do. Of course, default behavior can be overriden by extending the class.

That's why it's the question of a taste which technique to use: `CActiveForm` widget alone combining form fields' and buttons' declaration with their representation in a view file by calling convenient (required) methods of `CActiveForm` instance or `CForm` class declaring form's input specifications in a separate configuration file and customizing its rendering by pointing at appropriate active form widget and/or by overriding default rendering methods. The latter technique allows to reuse a form in several actions easily and is no more than [using form builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder).

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://www.essential-strategy.com/activeform) for live examples of ActiveForm, CForm, et cetera. You can also see the live Model, View & Controller files.